# GitHub Runner Error>> fatal: unable to access 'GithubRepoUrl.git': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github, markdown, github-actions, cicd

I encountered an issue when trying to create my contribution snake grid but my workflow was not passing through so I decided to share the solution which worked for me.
Here's what the error looks like;

[image: Runner Error]

```
Run ad-m/github-push-action@master
  with:
    github_token: ***
    branch: main
    force: true
    github_url: https://github.com
    directory: .
Push to branch main
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/KrAsH-CoD3/cont-snake-grid.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Invalid exit code: 128
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ad-m/github-push-action/master/start.js:29:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 128
}
Error: Invalid exit code: 128
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ad-m/github-push-action/master/start.js:29:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

It provides an Error 403 (No Permission Access). To fix this,

1. Navigate into the repo settings
2. Click the "Action" dropdown
3. Then "General"
4. Scroll down a little till you see "Workflow permissions"
5. It is probably on "Read repository contents and packages permissions"
6. Click "Read and write permissions"
7. Scroll down and save.

[image: Runner Pass]